# SQLite database returning wrong minimum ID

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm encountering a rather weird bug in a SQLite database: When sorting data via ID number, my returned minimum one is far above the second one (As a matter of fact, it'd even be the maximum).

My request is :

```
SELECT id FROM myTable ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10;
```

and my return values are :

```
id
 1. 47196
 2. 14421
 3. 16419
 4. 16420 
 5. 16421 
 6. 16422 
 7. 16423 
 8. 16424 
 9. 16425 
 10. 16426
```

Similar result with a "**SELECT MIN(id) FROM myTable;**", returning 47196

The field id is defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.
I'm looking for the root cause. My guess would be a form of corruption, but wouldn't SQLite detect the database as corrupted then?

Following Forpas idea, I tried :

```
SELECT id FROM myTable ORDER BY TRIM(id) + 0 ASC LIMIT 10;
```

this does fix the result, putting 14421 in first position.

My sqlite version is 3.6.19

If someone could explain what that'd mean and how such things can happen, I'd be grateful!

Comment: are you sure datatype of id is int?

Comment: Just in case there are leading spaces in the values run `SELECT id FROM myTable ORDER BY TRIM(id) + 0 ASC LIMIT 10;`

Comment: I guess your id column contains text, so please try `SELECT MIN(id), MIN(substr(id, INSTR(id, ' ')+1)) FROM myTable;`  https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=7c72d4c215c7b2169cf3b3f47d3c4677&php_version=null&sql_version=sqlite3

Comment: Since TRIM() fixes the problem this means that the column values contain leading spaces. Update the table with: `UPDATE myTable SET id = TRIM(id)`

Answer (score 0):

> The field id is defined as INTEGER.

> If someone could explain what that'd mean and how such things can happen, I'd be grateful!

Defining a column as INTEGER does not restrict the column to storing integer values. With one exception, that of the **[rowid](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)** column or an alias thereof, any column can store any of the types of values that can be stored.

- Perhaps have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9eecb7/9040 which demonstrates this.

It is this flexibility that you have fallen foul of. You are saving the value as a TEXT value and inadvertently introducing spaces and hence the issue when sorting.

You may wish to read [Data Types in SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), which includes :-

> Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.

- note that not defining an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column actually results in an extra hidden/special column that is an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, the **rowid** column. Using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY makes the column an alias of the **rowid** column (but unhidden).

  - Note that specifically INTEGER PRIMARY KEY i.e. INT PRIMARY KEY is NOT an alias of the **rowid** column).
  - AUTOINCREMENT can be used in addition to INTEGER PRIMARY KEY *(see the link above regarding AUTOINCREMENT)*.

Comment: Thank you for the additional informations. However, my row id is in fact an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.
Running the command `SELECT rowid FROM myTable` does give the same result as above, with the untrimmed 47196 coming first.
From sqlite.org, I've read that putting a non integer as a PK should have produced a "datatype mismatch" and prevent the operation.

Comment: @headdy  Try `SELECT rowid, typeof(rowid) ....` and also `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master where name = 'myTable';`. The first should show 47196 as integer. The second the sql used to create the table. Also `SELECT sqlite_version();`

Comment: the first one does show 47196 as integer
the second one return: 
`CREATE TABLE myTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, GUID TEXT, DateTime INTEGER, PsetID INTEGER, TightCode1 TEXT, TightCode2 TEXT, TightCode3 TEXT, TightCode4 TEXT, Markup BLOB)`
And for the sqlite version : `3.6.19` (not the freshest one, but unfortunately I wouldn't be able to upgrade it without a solid argument)

Comment: @headdy I would assume that it is corrupted but not sufficiently corrupted to be detected. I'd suggest creating a copy that isn't a file copy that is the equivalent of the unavailable (not introduced until 3.15.0) VACUUM INTO. So perhaps attach an empty db and copy the tables etc and then check to see if this fixes the issue.